Is drawing the の character in the ground a thing? [Konosuba]
In KonoSuba S1 (a comedy gag anime), Darkness (a masochist) wanted this Demon Lord to do unspeakable things to her. But the Demon Lord just nope'd the hell out and left, and Darkness was sulking over it. While sulking, she's crouched and drawing the の character in the ground over and over again.

Is this a thing? For example, I know drawing the 人 character in ones palm (and "eating" it) is a thing when you're nervous. I'm not aware of the の character being a thing though. Though I imagine she's just doodling aimlessly in the ground, and the の character is the kind of simple thing one would doodle over and over again. I'm just wondering if there's any more to it.

I knew about the gesture itself, but this is the first time I've learned it has a name and an entry in ordinary dictionaries:

のの字を書く
指先で、ひらがなの「の」を書くようなしぐさをする。若い女性が恥ずかしがったり、すねたりするときのしぐさをいう。

This is not a gesture specific to feeling down. It is an unconscious (fidgeting) gesture that is supposed to be done when someone doesn't know what to do because they are bored, embarrassed, scolded, etc. It is considered a cute gesture typically associated with girls. の can also be drawn with their toe while standing.
I couldn't find when this expression started to be used, but this dictionary entry means the gesture has been recognized for quite some time. I believe it is called as such simply because an aimless doodle looks like the shape of the character の. The character itself does not have any special meaning.
